# Incorrect function when creating handle for driver

Tags: c++, driver

For some reason when I try creating a handle for a driver, I'm getting `incorrect function.` (i.e error message 1). Does that mean I'm using the wrong function to create the handle? What am I doing wrong here?

```
std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if(errorMessageID == 0)
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}


int main()
{
    HANDLE hDriver = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\myDevice", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                  0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    cout << GetLastErrorAsString() << endl;  //"Wrong function"
                                             //hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    CloseHandle(hDriver);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `GetLastErrorAsString()` isn't part of WIN32. Perhaps you should post the code to it too.

Comment: Sorry I editted it in, it's the string description of GetLastError()

Comment: Is this a driver you are developing, or that is otherwise "not fully baked"?  Improper driver code can make all sorts of things go wrong, of course (:

Comment: Yes, but I'd imagine I can at least create a handle. The driver is installed/loaded as well

Comment: I don't know much about driver development, but I do see on the web examples of getting this error due to the driver not being set up quite right. Eg: https://www.winvistatips.com/threads/unable-to-open-device-with-createfile-error-1-error_invalid_function.187304/   Not sure what your specific situation might be, though.

Comment: faster of all need look error in driver. how it handle(if handle at all) *IRP_MJ_CREATE* win32 error 1 not enough informative here. need look better for *RtlGetLastNtStatus*

Comment: Ahh I just forgot to initialize driverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE]